# Использование библиотек LGPL-v2.1 в android проектах

Tags: android, лицензирование

Привет! Меня интересует вопрос использования библиотек с лицензией LGPL-v2.1 в моём android приложении. Конкретно tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-java:0.5.1 .

Посмотрев саму лицензию я понял что ничем не ограничен так как подключаю её "динамически" через gradle ("work that uses the library"), но поискав по форумам понял что люди в этом сомневаются, так как библиотека у меня включена в APK "исполняющий" файл, что определяется лицензией уже как "work based on the library".

Так как же мне оформить приложение с библиотекой LGPL-v2.1?